# Regex to include only first encounter of "-" and "."

Tags: python, regex, floating-point, data-cleaning

I have the following regex `\.(?![^.]+$)|[^-0-9.]` which cleans out all characters from a number and keeps only the first '.' (hence matches last) as it can be a float. However, some numbers can also be negative and/or have '-' within, as so:

```
-1.06581.4e-14
```

How can I make the regex I already have, also match the last encounter of negative sign only?
My final number would have to look as so:

```
-1.06581414
```

Comment: Your description doesn't match your example... Last '.' or first '.'? Can you give some more examples so we have a bit more to work with?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @jwismar sorry for the confusion, basically it has to match the last of ‘.’ and ‘-‘ so that it can delete. I’ve edited the q now

Comment: @Toto that would be Regex in python

Comment: You might want to research e notation, because what you're asking for can be done in regex, but it's very wrong. It's "exponential format" in the print options.

Answer (score 1):

If we wish to replace `.` and `e` in scientific numbers, this expression might do so, which I have added several optional boundaries, since I was not so sure about other inputs:

```
([-+]?\d+)(\.\d+)?((\.)(\d+)(e)([-+])(\d+))?
```

It has 8 capturing groups with all compartments of a scientific number, which we can simplify it, if necessary.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w5DYP4/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([-+]?\d+)(\.\d+)?((\.)(\d+)(e)([-+])(\d+))?"

test_str = ("-1.06581.4e-14\n"
    "1.06581.4e-14\n"
    "1.06581.4e+14\n"
    "+1.06581.4e-14\n"
    "+1.06581\n"
    "1.06\n"
    "1")

subst = "\\1\\2\\5\\8"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Demo

This snippet just shows that how the capturing groups work:

```js
const regex = /([-+]?\d+)(\.\d+)?((\.)(\d+)(e)([-+])(\d+))?/gm;
const str = `-1.06581.4e-14
1.06581.4e-14
1.06581.4e+14
+1.06581.4e-14
+1.06581
1.06
1`;
const subst = `$1$2$5$8`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your pattern and want to match the last occurrence of a hyphen you might add another alternation `|` to match a hyphen asserting what follows is not a hyphen using a negative lookahead `(?!.*-)`:

```
\.(?![^.]+$)|[^-0-9.]|-(?!.*-)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zK8ERZ/1)